# Flux.any correct use

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Flux.fromIterable(list of ids) . I want to find out if any of the record is null .So I am trying to use Flux.any but I see that I does not even print anything inside any and  directly goes to doOnEach as a result output is false. How can we fix this?
The solution should not be limited to null check.It can be any boolean condition.

```java
    Mono<Boolean> isAnyNull =Flux.fromIterable(request.getIds())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SomeException("No elements")))
        .flatMap(id->{
          return FooRepo.find(id);
          }).any(p->{
          System.out.println("check is any null p?."+p);
          return ((p==null)||(p.getId()==null));
        }).doOnEach(System.out::println);
```

I tried below as a temp weird fix but i am not sure if this is correct.Also I think it will only work for null.

```java
Mono<Boolean> isAnyNull = Flux.fromIterable(request.getds())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SomeException("No elements")))
        .flatMap(id -> {
          return FooRepo.find(id);
         })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SomeException("INVALID_ID"))).hasElements()
        .doOnEach(System.out::println);
```

**Update : This also works and check null using stream -Comments appreciated to improve**

```java
Flux.fromIterable(request.getIds())
     .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new SomeException("No elements")))
        .flatMap(id -> {
          return FooRepo.find(id);
        })
        .any(foo -> {
         return (Objects.nonNull(foo)||foo.getId()!=null);
        }).doOnEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Null value can not travel on Mono or Flux. You should use empty Mono/Flux instead.

Comment: I tried alternate approach which can check null. I will post in original.

Comment: @Yossarian if you have alternate working solution,please post. All that any requires is a Boolean condition.Ans regarding null we can check using Objects.nonNull

Comment: @VivekMisra Your description and your code don't match. You're asking if any records are null, but you physically *can't* have null records on a `Flux` - it'll just throw an exception. Try `Flux.just(null).subscribe();` to see. If you want to see if it matches any boolean condition, just call `Flux.any()` with a predicate. The code you say works does something rather different, looking up elements from some kind of repository.

Comment: @MichaelBerry The   List can be with no records. List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  Flux.just(list).subscribe();

Comment: @VivekMisra Not sure of your point there - of course it can, but that's very different from a `null` record...

Comment: So you see I do a find on flatmap a on each of Flux list and if result of  any of elements in give  null  I want to do different operation. Generally speaking, I want check some condition on each of elements returned from finder inside flatmap and if any of those do not satisfy I need to know.